# Angularjs appended $resource paramDefaults with special charaters

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have the following code

```
        var resource = $resource('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/' + DB_NAME + '/collections/' + collectionName + '/:id',
                             { apiKey:API_KEY, id:'@_id.$oid'},{update:{ method:'PUT' } }
    );
```

when i call

```
$scope.projects = Project.query({q:"+"});
```

referencing

> Each key value in the parameter object is first bound to url template if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search query after the ?.

I append the Get request with the string in the {}. I cannot however include special charaters. Is this a feature and how can I implement special characters?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should urlencode values as long as you are sending them in url query